Why am I getting 404 for every App Store Connect API endpoint?
When trying to access App Store Connect's API using an express.js router, I am constantly shown a 404 with each endpoint. I have gone through and made sure that my keys / issuer ID / paths to the private key are all correct.
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import fs from "fs";
import https from "https";

const router = express.Router();
const privateKeyFilePath = ".path/to/file"; 
const apiKeyId = process.env.API_KEY_ID; 
const issuerId = process.env.ISSUER_ID; 

// Authentication middleware
const authenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = await generateJWT(privateKeyFilePath, apiKeyId, issuerId);
    req.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to authenticate:", error);
    res.status(401).json({ error: "Failed to authenticate" });
  }
};

async function generateJWT(privateKeyPath, apiKeyId, issuerId) {
  try {
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyPath).toString();
    const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const exp = now + 1200; 

    const payload = {
      iss: issuerId,
      exp: exp,
      aud: "appstoreconnect-v1",
    };

    const signOptions = {
      algorithm: "ES256",
      header: {
        alg: "ES256",
        kid: apiKeyId,
        typ: "JWT",
      },
    };

    return jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, signOptions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to generate JWT:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

router.get("/", authenticate, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Make authenticated request to App Store Connect API
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps`,
      {
        headers: req.headers,
        agent: new https.Agent({
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
        }),
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch options from App Store Connect API");
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    res.json(data.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("API request failed:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});

export default router;

I have gone through all of the App Store Connect API documentation and watched dozens of videos. The JWT process seems correct but my assumption is somehow that is what is throwing this off. Does anyone have any suggestions? Note: I've also been looking at this nonstop since Friday because I am over a deadline, so I could just be missing something small. TIA
